# How to position text at the top of button element (and above background image)?

Tags: css

This is the look I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

I'm trying to position the text above the background image OR position the background image below the text, AND have the image and the text be clickable as it is a `button`.

But I can't get the text at the top of the `button`. `vertical-align` doesn't have any effect it seems.

Is it possible to do it with a single button element?

```css
       button {
        width: 96px;
        height: 150px;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 0px;
        line-height: 100px;
        background-position: 50% 58px;
        background-size: contain;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-color: transparent;
        margin: 20px;
      }

         button.document {
          border: 1px solid red;
        }
```

```html
<button     class="document"
            style="background-image: url(http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iynque/flat-ios7-style-documents/96/doc-icon.png)">
    Plot Plan.doc
    </button>
```

Comment: instead of height you can use padding-bottom: 115px;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove your `line-height` and add `padding-bottom` to offset the text:

```css
button {
        width: 96px;
        height: 150px;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 0px;
        background-position: 50% 58px;
        background-size: contain;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-color: transparent;
        margin: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 125px; 
      }


         button.document {
          border: 1px solid red;
        }
```

```html
<button     class="document"
            style="background-image: url(http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iynque/flat-ios7-style-documents/96/doc-icon.png)">
Plot Plan.doc
    </button>
```

Comment: I can accept the answer in 58 seconds. Well, 52 now.

Answer (score 2):

Mine is a modification of James Montagne's. I removed height (which should be a factor of content + (padding/image) and positioned the button to appear at the bottom of the element.

The way this works in CSS is first, it outputs all text, giving about 40px (Y) of content. Then, it adds 96px of padding below - enough extra space to contain the background image. Finally, it uses background-position to decide where to put the background image; at the bottom. This reduces the coupling of each "position variable", which might make it easier to change.

```css
button {
        width: 96px;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 0px;
        background-position: 50% bottom;
        background-size: contain;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-color: transparent;
        margin: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 96px; 
      }


         button.document {
          border: 1px solid red;
        }
```

```html
<button     class="document"
            style="background-image: url(http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iynque/flat-ios7-style-documents/96/doc-icon.png)">
Plot Plan.doc
    </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best I could get:

```css
button {
        width: 96px;
        height: 150px;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 0px;
        background-position: 10% 140%;
        background-size: contain;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-color: transparent;
        margin: 20px;
      }


         button.document {
          border: 1px solid red;
        }
```

```html
<button     class="document"
            style="background-image: url(http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iynque/flat-ios7-style-documents/96/doc-icon.png)">
Plot Plan.doc
    </button>
```

Added some background positioning `background-position: 10% 140%;` - 10% for horizontal and 140% for vertical positioning.